# Как поменять данные внутренних файлов Heroku? _app.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, бот, heroku

Залил бота на Heroku и столкнулся с такой проблемой. Как решить на компе понимаю, но как получить доступ к файлам внутри Heroku?

```
File /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/websocket/_app.py, line 231, in teardown 

if thread and thread.isAlive(): AttributeError: Thread object has no attribute isAlive
```

Comment: В `websocket`, что на хероку, есть ошибка и вы не знаете как использовать другую версию библиотеки или исправить текущую?

Comment: ну то есть для работы бота в оффлайне нужно просто сменить в сокете isAlive на is_alive. Но как получит доступ туда или исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Накидал monkey patch (проверял на 3.9)

Пример:

```
from threading import Thread

setattr(Thread, 'isAlive', getattr(Thread, 'is_alive'))

print(Thread().isAlive)
print(Thread().is_alive)
# <bound method Thread.is_alive of <Thread(Thread-1, initial)>>
# <bound method Thread.is_alive of <Thread(Thread-2, initial)>>
```

Но, конечно, лучше дождаться когда `websocket` исправит багу, а на `heroku` будет обновленная версия `websocket`

Comment: вы имеете ввиду что мне нужно добавить это в код своего бота?

Comment: @АлексейКожевников, ага

Comment: Вы волшебник, спасибо огромное

Comment: @АлексейКожевников, пожалуйста :)